# Refresh token is valid for 45 days in oneLogin

Tags: api, rest, twitter, onelogin

In OnLogin, Access token is valid for 10 hours and Refresh token is valid for 45 days.

I want to generate a new tokens(Refresh +Access Token) after 9.59hours.

My Question:

1. What will happen to the refresh token.Will it ever expire as I am generating the tokens(Refresh + Access token) for every 10 hours?
2. What is the best approach? Should I be refreshing the token or generating a new token for every 10 hours.
3. What can be done if the rate limit of 5000 is crossed with in an hour. Please suggest any alternatives.

Any suggestions or comments

Answer (score 2):

1. Nope. Refresh token lifespan is measured from when it gets created. If you create a new one via refresh it'll 'live' for 45 days. The allows you to hold on to the tokens and still be able to make a new access (and refresh) token even if you haven't used them for a long while.
2. Some folks choose to simply use the generate token call and use the clientID/Secret to constantly generate a new access token. But this is not as secure as using the access token to make calls until you get a response that it's expired, and then use the refresh token (and refresh token call) to get a new access / refresh pair. The minimizes the chances that your secret/clientID will ever get leaked.
3. Once you've exceeded 5000 / hour you're done for the hour. I'm curious what scenario you have that needs more calls than this.

This number can be raised for certain extraordinary circumstances (You're a giant customer with a big account) but that's between you and your customer service contact.

Comment: John: We have client logging in the morning with in an hour duration. we have client count  more than 10000+.If I generate a new access token,will I be able to reset the count back to 5000.

Comment: The limit is enforced per account, not per token.

Please talk to your customer service representative and open a support ticket - the limit is set on a per account basis, so we should be able to increase this for you.